# Php mysql - get the values of last days and total of entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to get the total values of last days into an array.
First, i have an array to get the last days:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$ldays = [];
$db = 6;
for($i=-$db; $i<=0; $i++) {
    array_push($ldays, date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$i days")));
}

//this will produce an array like this:
array (size=7)
  0 => string '2018-12-21' (length=10)
  1 => string '2018-12-22' (length=10)
  2 => string '2018-12-23' (length=10)
  3 => string '2018-12-24' (length=10)
  4 => string '2018-12-25' (length=10)
  5 => string '2018-12-26' (length=10)
  6 => string '2018-12-27' (length=10)
```

And now, i pull the total of values of each days from the database.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total, data FROM users WHERE data >= '2018-12-21' GROUP BY data ORDER BY data ASC
```

The output will be an array like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'total' => int 1
      'data' => string '2018-12-21' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'total' => int 1
      'data' => string '2018-12-24' (length=10)
```

As you can see, the array is missing some days, so i need to cross the 2 arrays and see if a day exists in the 2 arrays:

```
$response = [];

for($i=0; $i<count($ldays); $i++) {
    if(in_array($ldays[$i], array_column($rows_d, 'data'))) {
        $response[$ldays[$i]] = 'yes';
    }
    else {
        $response[$ldays[$i]] = 'no';
    }
}

//this will make an array like so:
array (size=7)
  '2018-12-21' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  '2018-12-22' => string 'no' (length=2)
  '2018-12-23' => string 'no' (length=2)
  '2018-12-24' => string 'yes' (length=3)
  '2018-12-25' => string 'no' (length=2)
  '2018-12-26' => string 'no' (length=2)
  '2018-12-27' => string 'no' (length=2)
```

But, insted of 'yes' and 'no', i want the array to be something like

```
array(size=7)
  '2018-12-21' => int 1
  '2018-12-22' => int 0 
  '2018-12-23' => int 0 
  '2018-12-24' => int 1 
  '2018-12-25' => int 0 
  '2018-12-26' => int 0 
  '2018-12-27' => int 0
```

and i keep getting an error if i do this :

```
if(in_array($ldays[$i], array_column($rows_d, 'data'))) {
    $response[$ldays[$i]] = $rows[$i]['total'];
}
else {
    $response[$ldays[$i]] = 0;
}
```

I guess this is because the rows array has only 2 entrys and the days array has 7. So, how can i obtain this? tks.

Comment: what is $row_d in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `in_array`, use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) combined with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to find the appropriate index into the `$rows` array instead:

```
if (($k = array_search($ldays[$i], array_column($rows_d, 'data'))) !== false) {
    $response[$ldays[$i]] = $rows_d[$k]['total'];
}
else {
    $response[$ldays[$i]] = 0;
}
```

Note that you have used both `$rows` and `$rows_d` in your code, I'm assuming it is supposed to be `$rows_d` in both cases.

Comment: Hi, tks. You are correct. `$rows` is wrong in my code. its supposed to be `$rows_d` Almost there. Tried your code but now it seems that index 0 (day 2018-12-21) is 0 instead of 1

Comment: @eskimopest Sorry - forgot the `!== false` test, that should fix the problem. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It can looks prettier

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
    $ldays = [];
    $db = 6;
    for($i=-$db; $i<=0; $i++) {
        $ldays[date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$i days"))] = 0;
    }

    $dbResult = [['total' => 1,'data' => '2018-12-21'],['total' => 2,'data' => '2018-12-24']]

    foreach ($dbResult as $v) {
        $ldays[$v['data']] = $v['total'];
    }

    var_dump($ldays);
```